# Update chart using chart.js and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chart.js

I am trying to create a donut chart using chart.js passing data through ajax function that is called with an onclick event. The problem is that the chart is not displayed although the data arrives.

This is the ajax function

```
// JavaScript Document 

var xmlhttp;

function generaGrafico(nome){
    xmlhttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlhttp == null){
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
        return;
    }

    var url = "php/creaGrafico.php";
    url = url+"?nome="+nome;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function stateChanged(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        var spanstat = document.getElementById("stats");
        spanstat.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        // code for IE6, IE5
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    return null;
}
```

this is creaGrafico.php

```
<script src="/newton/js/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<?php
include 'connessione.php';
$nome = $_GET["nome"];
$cn = connessione();
$query = 'SELECT Pv, Pp, Pb FROM risultati WHERE Name = "'.$nome.'"';
if ($result = $cn->query($query)){
    $vittorie = 0;
    $pareggi = 0;
    $bye = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $vittorie += $row[Pv];
        $pareggi += $row[Pp];
        $bye += $row[Pb];
        }
    }
else printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $result->error);
?>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var vittorie = <?php print $vittorie ?>;
var pareggi = <?php print $pareggi ?>;
var bye = <?php print $bye ?>;
var graficoRisultati = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'doughnut',
data: {
    labels: ["Vittorie", "Pareggi", "Bye"],
    datasets: [{
        data: [vittorie, pareggi, bye],
        backgroundColor: [
            '#4BC0C0',
            '#FF6384',
            '#FFCE56'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
    }
});
</script>
```

and this is where ajax is called

```
function classificaMagic(){
    $cn = connessione();
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM LM ORDER BY Punti DESC LIMIT 10';

    echo'
    <div id="content">
    <article class="post">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Classifica giuoco del Magic</h2><p>';
    if ($result = $cn->query($query)){
        echo'
        <table name="classificaMagic">';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $stampaNome = explode(", ", $row[Name]);
            echo'
            <tr onClick="generaGrafico(\''.$row[Name].'\')">
                <td>'.$stampaNome[1].' '.$stampaNome[0].'</td>
                <td>'.$row[Punti].'</td>
            </tr>';
        }

        echo'
        </table>
        </article> <!-- .post  -->
        <hr />
        </div> <!-- #content -->

        <aside id="sidebar">
            <div class="widget">
                <div id="stats"  style="width: 300; height: 300;"></div>
            </div>
        </aside>';

    }
    else printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $result->error);
}
```

as I said before , the data arrives , but the chart is created .
where am I wrong ?